# Parse.com Eager Loading one to many relationships Get Parent with children

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, eager-loading

I'm currently having an issue for the eager loading. Is there any way to get the parents with their children?

I have a Question Model that "has many" Answer Model related to it. Answers can be more than 100 so I did a pointer of the Question on each Answer "one to many" relation instead of storing an array of Answer pointers on the Question itself.

How can I get all my Questions with the 10 first answers of each question?

```
// this is what Parse.com says, but i want the opposit
var query = new Parse.Query(Answer);
query.include("Question");

// this is what i would like but not possible 
// because the pointer is on the Answer 
// so can't include it in a Question query
var query = new Parse.Query(Question);
query.include("Answers");
```

This does not work for me as in I want Questions with their Answers and not Answers with their parent Question

How can i eager load this?

Comment: store the answers in a column of type "Array of pointers"  . then in query  "include.Colum_array_ptrs"   and you get all the answers along with the question that points to them.

Comment: @RobertRowntree this can't work because a question can get more 200 answers like a forum thread kind of, and Parse recommends to not use array of pointers for this task

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have a question saved, represented by `questionId` and an answer saved represented by `answerId`; this is how you create the relationship

```
// adding answers to a specific question
var Question = Parse.Object.extend('Question');
var Answer = Parse.Object.extend('Answer');
var aQuestion = new Question({id: questionId});

var answersRelation = aQuestion.relation("answers");
answersRelation.add(new Answer({id: answerId}));
aQuestion.save();
```

Now this is how you get all of the answers for the specified question

```
// getting answers...
var Question = Parse.Object.extend('Question');
var aQuestion = new Question({id: questionId});

var answerRelation = aQuestion.relation("answers")
answerRelation.query().find().then(function(_answers){
    console.log("Answers for question " + aQuestion.get("name"), _answers);
}, function(_errors){
    console.log("Error:" + aQuestion.get("name"), _errors);
});
```

https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#objects-relational-data

Comment: i'm sorry but what you are suggesting doesn't give me the data of aQuestion because you didn't query it anywhere you only fetched the relation. Besides, you gave me a N:N db schema, i have i 1:N db schema